# Overlapping border div

Tags: html, css

i want to create a table just with `div` tag. I use only two class and it works well.
 
The only problem is the border of cell inside the table have double width of the table border and it looks ugly. I know the reason is all cell have border around but i can not fix it. I've try some solution in other post but it does not work in this case.
 
Can some one please help me? Thanks a lot. Note that i don't want to add more class.

```css
.row { 
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  border: solid 2px blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add negative margin `top` and `left` equal to width of the border.

```css
.row { 
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  border: solid 2px blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center; 
  margin-left: -2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS to override the border in certain conditions...

```css
.row {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  border: solid 2px blue;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.col+.col {
  border-left: none;
}

.row:first-of-type .col {
  border-top: solid 2px blue;
}

.row .row .col {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
  <div class="col">x</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class to wrap the content and add some style like:

```css
    .table{
      border: 2px solid blue;
     }
    .row { 
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .col {
      border: solid 2px blue;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 0;
      min-height: 1px;
      flex-grow: 1;
      max-width: 100%;
      text-align: center; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">x</div>
      <div class="col">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">x</div>
      <div class="col">x</div>
      <div class="col">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">x</div>
        <div class="col">x</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">x</div>
        <div class="col">x</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your styling for border under col class gets applied for both of the adjacent columns[cells]. If you do not want to add classes, try giving "id" and defining styles in CSS, or give inline styles. **Negative values in CSS are avoided in general.**

CSS:

```
.row { 
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  border-right: solid 2px black;
  border-top: solid 2px black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="border: solid 2px black;">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="border-top: none" class="col">x</div>
    <div style="border-top: none; border-right: none" class="col">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div style="border-right: none" class="col">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div class="col">x</div>
    <div style="border-right: none" class="col">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">x</div>
      <div style="border-right: none" class="col">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">x</div>
      <div style="border-right: none" class="col">x</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you say negative values in CSS are avoided in general?

Comment: A child element has to be within the parent. It will not be so if negative margin is given.

Comment: Yeah. But it is just 1px. It is no problem. Thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

@Duanxx

**Explanation for my answer:**

Look at the following code.[For code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEzpo.png)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .parentDiv{
        background-color: black;
        justify-content: space-around;
        display: flex;
      }
      .childDiv{
        width: 50%;
        height:100px;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 10px 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parentDiv">
        <div class="childDiv" style="background-color: pink">Child 1</div>
        <div class="childDiv" style="background-color: bisque">Child 2</div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Have a look at this now:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .parentDiv{
        background-color: black;
        justify-content: space-around;
        display: flex;
      }
      .childDiv{
        width: 50%;
        height:100px;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: -5px 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parentDiv">
        <div class="childDiv" style="background-color: pink">Child 1</div>
        <div class="childDiv" style="background-color: bisque">Child 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[For code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWpqH.png)

Compare the two. The children are supposed to **fit** inside the parent. That is why negative margins are not used.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. I know negative margins should not be used but in my case, i just use -1px. It will be fine and it is the best/fastest way to reach the result. Your answer is correct but these `div` will be genarated dynamic so it is hard and complicate to style for each `div`.